# How to add augmented images to original dataset with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I understand the function of `tf.image` augmentations, but I want to not only have the augmented images in my dataset, but also keep the original images as well. That way I will have the original, and many augmented versions, thus expanding the dataset. How can I do this in `TensorFlow` or `Keras`? Preferably by implemented in a data pipeline as well.